# Unrecognized application of absorption

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I got stuck on a proof on a test at the following step: $$\neg p \wedge (r \vee\neg p)\wedge (r \vee\neg q)$$

And my professor transformed this to: $$\neg p \wedge (r\vee\neg q)$$

And he justified this with the absorption law. However, I don't see how the absorption law, which as I understand it is: $$p\wedge (p\vee q)\equiv p$$ $$p\vee (p\wedge q)\equiv p$$applies in this case. It just doesn't seem to fit the pattern. Is there another "absorption" law he could be referring to?

Comment: Just to build some intuition, and to shorten and clean up proofs: more generally, absorption says that in $\;p \land \ldots\;$, one may assume that $\;p \equiv \text{true}\;$ throughout the right hand part.  And similarly for $\;p \lor \ldots\;$, one may assume that $\;p \equiv \text{false}\;$ throughout the right hand part.  (These more general absorption laws follow from the ones you quote, by induction on the structure of propositional expressions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that, since $\vee$ is communative, $r \vee\neg p$ is the same as $\neg p \vee r$. So we transform it to

$$\neg p \wedge (\neg p \vee r)\wedge (r \vee\neg q)$$

$$[\neg p \wedge (\neg p \vee r)] \wedge (r \vee\neg q)$$

The absorption theorem is applied on $\neg p$ and $r$ to get:

$$\neg p \wedge (r \vee\neg q)$$

Comment: Yes, I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In $p\wedge(p\vee q)$ substitute $\neg p$ for $p$ and substitute $r$ for $q$.

Also realize that $\vee$ is commutative.

Comment: Yes, thank you.